# Configure Schema Registry compatibility in upsert-like strategy

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have schema registry with `FULL_TRANSITIVE` compatibility in order to be able to read old data with new schema and vice-versa, and this is completely fine for my purposes.

The problem is that I need have in some place (schema registry possibly, the last version of the schema) the *fully merged* schema for my subject.

Let's have an example (everything is Avro):

1. I write data `{"foo" :"foo", "bar":"bar"}` with the corresponding schema with `foo` and `bar` as optional string fields, so we have schema version `1` for that subject.
2. Then, I write `{"foo" :"foo", "bar":"bar", "baz":"baz"}`, where `baz` is optional string field (+ `foo` and `bar`), and so the schema evolves, putting also `baz`, we have schema version `2`.
3. Now I write  `{"foo" :"foo", "bar":"bar", "id":"id"}`, where `id` is optional string field (+ `foo` and `bar`, but now **without** `baz`, that's the *problem* here) The schema evolves, putting also `id`, and we have schema version `3`.

The issue here is that in the last step, in the schema version `3`, i have only `foo`, `bar`, `id` as field, and even though I can read and write perfectly thanks to the `FULL_TRANSITIVE` compatibility, I don't have in any place the full schema with all `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and `id`, that are string optional fields.

Is there a way to obtain such behavior in schema registry, so maintaining the `FULL_TRANSITIVE` compatibility but having the *complete* schema (with all the possibile values) as the last version of the schema, but with the requirement that I can't put the complete schema with missing fields, but only with fields included in the payload?

I was thinking about asking the latest schema before writing the record, in order to build the complete record, but probably is not good for performances.

Thank you

Comment: Unclear how you are writing a message without providing the schema for that message that includes all relevant (optional) fields